# Vertically aligning Labels and TextBlocks at Top in XAML

Tags: xaml, label, textblock

How can I vertically align a `Label` and `TextBlock` at `Top` so that their first lines of text line up?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">Some Label:</Label>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">Some text<TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

The above code gives me this:

[Vertically misaligned Label and TextBlock text http://img156.imageshack.us/img156/4940/labeltextblock.png](http://img156.imageshack.us/img156/4940/labeltextblock.png)

Comment: The question's code is quite broken. The Label and TextBlock are both in column 0, row 0, and appear on top of each other. The TextBlock "closing" tag is actually a 2nd TextBlock _opening_ tag so I'm guessing the code wasn't copied from a working example. (The image for this old question is also broken.) Tested 2021-07-17.

Comment: The edit queue is full, but corrected question code:

```
<Grid>
 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition />
  <ColumnDefinition />
 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition />
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
 <Label Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">A</Label>
 <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top">B</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The extra space around the label comes from the Padding property. To remove the space, you can explicitly set the Padding property to "0" directly on the Label, or, of course, set it via a Style.

Comment: It seems that a Label's Padding is set to 5 by default, and a TextBlock's is set to 0.

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: The problem begins when the FontSize is different between the two controls.

Comment: Thanks for unveiling one of the mysteries of WPF to me

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextBlock>
<InlineUIContainer BaselineAlignment="Top"><Label Content="Label"/></InlineUIContainer>
<InlineUIContainer BaselineAlignment="Top"><TextBlock>TextBlock Content</TextBlock>                 </InlineUIContainer>
</TextBlock>
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround: [Align bottoms of text in controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035943/align-bottoms-of-text-in-controls).

I posted a connection: https://connect.microsoft.com/WPF/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=523432, please vote.