# WPF Labels not vertically aligning to the bottom of the Grid

Tags: wpf, grid, label, vertical-alignment

I have a Grid, with two columns and one row, thus making two cells. Each cell contains a label. One label has the default font size, while the other is set to 20 and both have their Vertical Alignment attribute set to Bottom BUT there is a two pixel difference between where they sit in the (As illustrated in my lovely image below).

[image: Example of Pixel difference]

Now is this expected and a working part of WPF? As I would expect them to both sit on the same line. The only way I can currently think of doing this is fiddling around with the margin values.

```
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="125"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="Notes" FontSize="20"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
      <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Content="(Max something 1,00)" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    </Grid>
```

**Answered** Sheridan's answer as correct. Although I didn't use his exact implementation for mine, but one of his [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035943/align-bottoms-of-text-in-controls) gave the answer that was relevant to my code and follows the same principle. I've included my code below for anyone else who is trying this.

```
        <Grid>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="125"/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="20" LineHeight="44" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">Notes</TextBlock>
          <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" LineHeight="44" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">(something else 1,000)   </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many answers to this question that can be found online. One example is the [Align bottoms of text in controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035943/align-bottoms-of-text-in-controls) post here on Stack Overflow. However, most of the answers (like that one) suggest that you have to write code to fix this issue. I disagree with them. You can use the [`BaselineAlignment` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.inline.baselinealignment%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the `Inline` class to do this for you. Try something like this:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Span FontSize="40">Notes</Span>
    <Span BaselineAlignment="Baseline">(Max something 1,00)</Span>
</TextBlock>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That "issue" appears because of your font + size of your font.

What actually happens there is this: your Label has a specific border(size) and the font is **centered** in that "box". Vertical-alignment sets the **box** at bottom, so the proper **text** will not be modified.

[image: Here you can see the difference of your Labels size]

Comment: That makes sense, but how can I set the text to be the bottom of that box as well?

Comment: You can by setting the margin-top ( You have to resize that box : manually - with cursor or automatic by adding margin-top)